# if-clause addings empty

Tags: php, variables, if-statement

i have the following if-clause:

```
if(empty($var)){
                $errors[]="Failure";
            }
```

this is for a form that will be display an errormessage when a user has made no entries. i would like to hide this field when a user has made something specific so that he cant see this input field. this div will only being displayed when another variable is set. because of the "empty" problem i got the errormessage even when there is no inputfield. so my question is:

how can i add further terms to that clause that it will be like:

```
if(empty($var) only when $var2===true ){
    $errors[]="Failure";
            }
```

i already tried to use && but this doesn't work the correct way. thats why i'm asking and thought maybe there is another way. thanks to all.

Comment: so if $var2 is true and $var is empty, it should error out?

Comment: exactly, when $var (inputfield) is empty the onliest way it should show errormessage should be when $var2 is true.

Comment: Sudhir's answer solve your problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
if(empty($var) AND $var2) {
    $errors[]="Failure";
}
```

If $var is empty and $var2 is TRUE it will be inside the if condition. did you mean something like that

Comment: yes thats it. i thought there would be no difference between && / AND. hmm... thanks alot.

Answer (score 0):

Probably `$var2` is `1` and not `true`, because in other case this need to work

```
if(empty($var) && $var2===true){
    $errors[]="Failure";
}
```

Try

```
if(empty($var) && $var2==true){
    $errors[]="Failure";
}
```

**`==`** instead of **`===`** or check for logical bugs.